# Javascript for Date

Tags: javascript

i ve two date controls, when i select a particular date the next date should be automatically set with a year diff
For example:  start date: 26/03/2011 the next date should be 25/03/2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = new Date(); // or however you set this starting point
y = d.getFullYear();

d2 = d;
d2.setFullYear(y + 1);
```